# Apple Mach-O Linker Error while loading iOS Application

Tags: ios, linker-errors

I am getting this error by trying to launch my iOS Application.

```
ld: file not found: /Users/tomkortney/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Hello_&_World_Application-aiizoqrzgnuqfuecelrkyaxgisik/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Hello & World Application.app/Hello & World Application
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I have red bunch of similar Stack Overflow questions similar to mine, but none of those helped me to solve this issue.

I guess that there is a problem with "&" symbol.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove reference of your third party from Xcode and add it again. Clean the code by using:
`Xcode-->Product+(Press option key)-->Clean Build Folder`

Make build it again.

Hope it helps!

Comment: That was my first try. Despite of clean build and derived data deleting, I am still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Generally overwriting project may cause this prolems.Try this method.

-UPDATE - Clang error - Mach-O Linker error

In some case error log window displaying .xctest error, to fix it

-> Select your project

-> Beside this(just before General tab) select your projectTest file from dropdown

-> There is one option (like ProjNameTests)

-> In Host Application, select your project from dropdown only if it show custom

Happy Coding :)

[image]

Comment: I have tried "Host Application" fix. I am still getting the same error.